# Powershell formatting issue

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, scripting

So i'm trying to get a custom format from an array that should look like this

[image]

and i want to add an extra column for the sorting count, but as you can see the order is not correct as it should look like col1 col2 col3 and the col4 for the counting part.. here is what i have done so far

```
$arr=@();
$Properties = @{col1=$sen;col2=$sub;col3=$r_d;};
$Newobject = New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties;
$arr+=$Newobject;
$arr = $arr | sort-object @{Expression={$_.Col3}; Ascending=$false};
$t = @{Expression={$_.Count};Label="Col4"};
$arr = $arr | group | % { $h = @{} } { $h[$_.Col2] = $_.Count } { $h | Format-Table $t -AutoSize };
```

Comment: That's some horribly convoluted code you have there. I *golfed* PowerShell code and it sometimes was more readable than this. Your `Sort-Object` for example could just be `Sort-Object col3 -Descending`. Using hash tables has the problem that the order is unpredictable; there might be better options here. But honestly, I would first have to understand what exactly it is what you're doing there ...

Comment: Well i'm trying to print an array in that format + an extra column for counting by the 'col3'

Comment: You have several options. 1) Create a custom type and setup a default view using the information you can find in `Get-Help about_Types.ps1xml` (it's also possible to configure the default view using the cmdlet `Update-FormatData`). 2) If you are using newer PS versions than 2.0 you can ensure that the hash table is an ordered dictionary. Just case it to an ordered dictionary like `$Properties = [ordered]@{ col1...`. 3) When you want to display the properties, use the `Select-Object` cmdlet providing the properties in the order you want them displayed.

Comment: Thanks, how about counting by 'col3' how i can achieve this?        `$t = @{Expression={$_.Value};Label="Email(s)"};
$arr = $arr | group | % { $h = @{} } { $h[$_.Col3] = $_.Count } { $h | Format-Table $t -AutoSize };`

Comment: This is a separate question and if you are not able to solve the problem yourself I suggest you create a new so question for it (but do try to find a solution yourself first).